# 3-way switch not working properly

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a 3 way switch at the top of the stairs and one at the bottom that control the lights in the stairway/hall way.  The problem that I have is that you can only turn the lights on from the same switch that the lights were last turned off from.

I have looked at many websites and videos and haven't quite seen the setup that I have. The home is not that old (13 years). I am not the original owner but I suspect that the house was originally wired this way because when I took off the wall plate, I had to cut the paint away from the wall plate and the screws looked fairly new still.

Unlike everything that I have seen online, the junction box with the hot black wire has another cable that examples don't show. For the sake of this description, I'll name Cable #1 as the cable housing the hot black wire. It is a 14-2 cable. Cable #2 is a 14-3 wire houses the red wire. Cable #3 is another 14-2 cable. Anyway, here is what I found.

**Switch 1** has the following connections:

All ground wires are connected together.

From 14-2 Cable #1 with the hot wire:
Hot Black wire connected to common screw.
White neutral is to another 14-2 Cable #3 and is connected to the black wire.

Cable #2 is a 14-3 wire:
Black and Red are connected to switch 1 gold terminals
The white is connected to the white wire from Cable #3

I do not know where Cable #3 is going. I am assuming it is to one of the light fixtures.

**Switch 2**

The black wire is connected to the common screw.
The red and white wires are connected to the gold terminals.

I have checked the voltage in switch 2 with the power on and switch one in the up position, I have 120v at the black and white screws with switch 2 in the up position. The red screw shows a voltage of about 60V. When I put switch 2 in the down position, the red screw now shows a voltage of 120V as well as the black common screw. The white now has very little current showing (about 3V).  When switch 1 is in the down position (so that current should flow through the red wire), there is no current at switch 2.

I tried disregarding Cable #3 and connected the white wires together from cables 1 and 2. This resulted in blowing the circuit.

Also, I have moved all of the wires around at switch 2. The effect was that the lights came on with the switch in the down position but I still could not turn the lights on at switch 1.

I know this is a lot of information. Perhaps, I should either call a pro or live with the way it is but, I wanted to try and figure this out.  Thanks for any help you can give.

[image: Switch 1]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Sorry about stomping on your first post, but I've renamed your cables for reasons pertaining to copyright and regional unfamiliarity. I hope it hasn't detracted from the clarity of the question.

Comment: Also, consider sketching this up and posting a pic. Anyone short of the tradesman version of Rain Man attempting to help will probably have to do so himself, so you'll get more assistance if you do it.

Comment: You might also want to open up the lights, and take a look at the wiring in those boxes.  Then you'll  have a better understanding of the wiring. Trial-and-error wiring is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Has this ever worked?

Comment: I have owned the home for 1 1/2 years. It hasn't worked properly since I have owned it. I  will come up with a diagram. I thought about taking the light fixtures down and at least seeing if I can trace the wires. Maybe that will be next weekends project.

Comment: @CanthonyC [This answer](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33) describes how to add photos.

Answer (score 2):

## This is a guess!!!

This is *only* a guess. Further investigation is needed to determine how the circuit is wired, and nothing further should be done until you have a complete understanding of the current wiring.

Based on your description, this is how I **think** it may be wired.

[image]

If this is indeed the case, then changing the wiring as follows, should get things working.

[image]

Notice I've swapped the black and white wires at `Switch 2`. I've also swapped the black and white wires from `Cable #3`, in the first switch box.  Finally, I've marked the white wire from `Cable #2` at both ends, to indicate that it is being used as a ungrounded  (hot) conductor.

## WARNING!!!

This answer is only a **GUESS**. You'll have to verify this wiring yourself, **before** making any changes. Trial-and-error wiring is **not** safe, and should never be done.

If you need further assistance once you have more information,  please comment on this answer. I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try and trace the 3rd cable and determine for sure where it is going.

Answer (score 0):

Update, I was able to confirm the path of the wires from cable 3 by using a multi-meter and testing for and confirming continuity. Even though it would seem logical that cable 2 goes from switch one to switch two, I tested the wires there as well just to confirm. After studying the diagram from "tester101", I was able to understand the chart which makes sense to me. I did make the suggested connections and now the light works as it should. The 3-way switches now allow me to turn the lights on and off from either switch. Thanks so much for your help Tester101.